# npm did not generate an js file, but the page html need when access that page

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, pm2

I have a `demo.com` nuxt project in my centos8 server,

I use npm to generate `.nuxt` directory:

```
[root@dodo demo.com]# npm run build

> Demo@1.0.0 build /www/wwwroot/demo.com
> NODE_ENV=production nuxt build

ℹ Production build                                                                                                                                                       10:38:55
✔ Builder initialized                                                                                                                                                    10:38:55
✔ Nuxt files generated                                                                                                                                                   10:38:55

 WARN  Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:                                                                                                               10:38:56
npx browserslist@latest --update-db


✔ Client
  Compiled successfully in 19.11s

✔ Server
  Compiled successfully in 3.28s


Hash: 71f8ef64b1146d935171
Version: webpack 4.43.0
Time: 19112ms
Built at: 2021-06-10 10:39:15 ├F10: AM┤
                         Asset       Size  Chunks                                Chunk Names
../server/client.manifest.json   22.7 KiB          [emitted]                     
       01da9a8a4338015f77f5.js  915 bytes   12, 4  [emitted] [immutable]         pages/contact_us/index
       1ffba14833e4bdf95a5c.js  483 bytes       3  [emitted] [immutable]         pages/_lang/cloudservers/index
       207aa5e89ad957a2f3c6.js   1.62 KiB       7  [emitted] [immutable]         pages/_lang/index
       2d3260d317f2f425e834.js   1.77 KiB   15, 7  [emitted] [immutable]         pages/index
       3331db0cbf9ae49a5375.js  757 bytes       4  [emitted] [immutable]         pages/_lang/contact_us/index
       43776824d2c082dd6ebf.js    5.5 KiB   14, 6  [emitted] [immutable]         pages/dedicated_servers/index
       4489ea5c0f99d0f999fb.js  641 bytes   11, 3  [emitted] [immutable]         pages/cloudservers/index
       4c2c9e2e073184e0eb10.js   5.35 KiB       6  [emitted] [immutable]         pages/_lang/dedicated_servers/index
       5731055eace9dd208b58.js    988 KiB      19  [emitted] [immutable]  [big]  vendors.app
       5ea2309f01b679fcae26.js   5.61 KiB   10, 2  [emitted] [immutable]         pages/cdn/index
       7dbc71ae5886fb45568c.js   1.05 KiB       8  [emitted] [immutable]         pages/_lang/operations/index
       81ed7f54dd8bb7dbe8b9.js    1.2 KiB   16, 8  [emitted] [immutable]         pages/operations/index
       83369477c447a3891c43.js   2.68 KiB      18  [emitted] [immutable]         runtime
       8e787e9d618a5003de48.js  486 bytes       5  [emitted] [immutable]         pages/_lang/containers/index
                      LICENSES   2.27 KiB          [emitted]                     
       a906b5413b35e8c20e66.js   2.16 KiB   17, 9  [emitted] [immutable]         pages/promotions/index
       adb6c68f15baf98d21e7.js   5.46 KiB       2  [emitted] [immutable]         pages/_lang/cdn/index
       aea42c0d73dca11a250f.js   2.01 KiB       9  [emitted] [immutable]         pages/_lang/promotions/index
       b2bb49f694004557f0db.js    188 KiB       1  [emitted] [immutable]         commons.app
       e59b70f7e84824d7889b.js   59.2 KiB       0  [emitted] [immutable]         app
       eee416780835006e0256.js  644 bytes   13, 5  [emitted] [immutable]         pages/containers/index
               img/822014b.jpg   89.9 KiB          [emitted]                     
               img/8d21021.png   33.6 KiB          [emitted]                     
               img/a1a93c7.jpg   33.2 KiB          [emitted]                     
               img/a2dd91d.png    362 KiB          [emitted]              [big]  
               img/d4522c3.png    598 KiB          [emitted]              [big]  
               img/d75f2b5.png   16.9 KiB          [emitted]                     
            videos/0c58938.mp4   7.83 MiB          [emitted]              [big]  
            videos/9d8d441.mp4   5.12 MiB          [emitted]              [big]  
            videos/cb287d0.mp4      9 MiB          [emitted]              [big]  
            videos/e583b13.mp4   9.25 MiB          [emitted]              [big]  
 + 2 hidden assets
Entrypoint app [big] = 83369477c447a3891c43.js b2bb49f694004557f0db.js 5731055eace9dd208b58.js e59b70f7e84824d7889b.js

WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
This can impact web performance.
Assets: 
  videos/9d8d441.mp4 (5.12 MiB)
  videos/e583b13.mp4 (9.25 MiB)
  img/d4522c3.png (598 KiB)
  img/a2dd91d.png (362 KiB)
  videos/cb287d0.mp4 (9 MiB)
  videos/0c58938.mp4 (7.83 MiB)
  5731055eace9dd208b58.js (988 KiB)

WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (1000 KiB). This can impact web performance.
Entrypoints:
  app (1.21 MiB)
      83369477c447a3891c43.js
      b2bb49f694004557f0db.js
      5731055eace9dd208b58.js
      e59b70f7e84824d7889b.js


Hash: f1c125b58fecbfbaa618
Version: webpack 4.43.0
Time: 3285ms
Built at: 2021-06-10 10:39:18 ├F10: AM┤
                  Asset        Size  Chunks                         Chunk Names
12667791963e0ea9d245.js   625 bytes   10, 2  [emitted] [immutable]  pages/cloudservers/index
1ef7d6c81a96c8ffe637.js   464 bytes       2  [emitted] [immutable]  pages/_lang/cloudservers/index
347c4119b3e66fbb4c5a.js   775 bytes       3  [emitted] [immutable]  pages/_lang/contact_us/index
60abca922a834513280c.js    2.15 KiB       8  [emitted] [immutable]  pages/_lang/promotions/index
799eeb663aef4ea0d369.js    1.63 KiB       6  [emitted] [immutable]  pages/_lang/index
7c3e9617dcc4c0aca732.js    5.61 KiB       1  [emitted] [immutable]  pages/_lang/cdn/index
7d469cf37421bc40b04b.js    1.07 KiB       7  [emitted] [immutable]  pages/_lang/operations/index
82a1eabc08a70b8e2809.js     2.3 KiB   16, 8  [emitted] [immutable]  pages/promotions/index
925d80aa1d1b3daff5d4.js    5.53 KiB   13, 5  [emitted] [immutable]  pages/dedicated_servers/index
94ed26b62699d2830429.js   628 bytes   12, 4  [emitted] [immutable]  pages/containers/index
99b21085a2fffb2c76f5.js    5.77 KiB    9, 1  [emitted] [immutable]  pages/cdn/index
e875bd84d186eead2579.js    5.38 KiB       5  [emitted] [immutable]  pages/_lang/dedicated_servers/index
f1e78e1076e3e3f4dd8f.js   467 bytes       4  [emitted] [immutable]  pages/_lang/containers/index
f77cbe309d9b5b390582.js   936 bytes   11, 3  [emitted] [immutable]  pages/contact_us/index
fc46011b6b9ff49920bc.js    1.22 KiB   15, 7  [emitted] [immutable]  pages/operations/index
fecbd7d89d7d1d4083cc.js    1.79 KiB   14, 6  [emitted] [immutable]  pages/index
              server.js     254 KiB       0  [emitted]              app
   server.manifest.json  1020 bytes          [emitted]              
Entrypoint app = server.js
```

it generated success:

```
[root@zengcloud demo.com]# ls -al .nuxt/
all 104
drwxr-xr-x  6 www  www   4096 Jun  10 10:38 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 www  www   4096 Jun 10 10:38 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  4583 Jun 10 10:38 App.js
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    98 Jun 10 10:38 bootstrap-vue.js
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 18037 Jun 10 10:38 client.js
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   136 Jun  10 10:38 components
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root    32 Jun 10 10:38 dist
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    58 Jun  10 10:38 empty.js
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  7663 Jun  10 10:38 index.js
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1928 Jun  10 10:38 loading.html
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   174 Jun  10 10:38 middleware.js
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    50 Jun  10 10:38 mixins
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  4179 Jun  10 10:38 router.js
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  2504 Jun  10 10:38 router.scrollBehavior.js
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  8371 Jun  10 10:38 server.js
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1480 Jun  10 10:38 store.js
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 16098 Jun  10 10:38 utils.js
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    47 Jun  10 10:38 views
```

you see the time is my execute success time.

but when I access the demo.com in my Chrome, there is a `12ea5675bfff21770e37.js` file can not found :

[image]

and you see when `npm run build`, there did not generate it.

Comment: What `html` file is loaded when you go to demo.com? Are you serving it with `nuxt start`? If you're pointing nginx directly to the directory, you should use `nuxt generate` (instead of `nuxt build`) to create a static build in `dist/` that nginx can serve directly.

Comment: Is there any cache server running? Is it cleared each time you rebuild your nuxt project?

Comment: Have you tried reproduce this process on another machine? e.g. I have nodejs on my local PC (Windows) and when I test things, even after a successful deployment, I'll try it on the shared server at work...